# iText7: com.itextpdf.kernel.PdfException: Dictionary doesn't have supported font data

Tags: itext, itext7

I try to generate a toc(table of content) for my pdf, and I want to get some strings which look like chapter title in xxx.pdf using ITextExtractionStrategy. But I got com.itextpdf.kernel.PdfException when I am running a test.

Here is my code:

```
    @org.junit.Test
    public void test() throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader("src/test/resources/template/xxx.pdf"),
                new PdfWriter(baos));

        pdfDoc.addNewPage(1);
        Document document = new Document(pdfDoc);

        // when add this code, throw com.itextpdf.kernel.PdfException: Dictionary doesn't have supported font data.
        Paragraph title =  new Paragraph(new Text("index"))
                .setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
        document.add(title);

        SimpleTextExtractionStrategy extractionStrategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();
        for (int i = 1; i < pdfDoc.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
            PdfPage page = pdfDoc.getPage(i);
            PdfCanvasProcessor parser = new PdfCanvasProcessor(extractionStrategy);
            parser.processPageContent(page);
        }
        ...

        document.close();
        pdfDoc.close();
        new FileOutputStream("./yyy.pdf").write(baos.toByteArray());
    }
```

Here is the output:

```
com.itextpdf.kernel.PdfException: Dictionary doesn't have supported font data.

    at com.itextpdf.kernel.font.PdfFontFactory.createFont(PdfFontFactory.java:123)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.canvas.parser.PdfCanvasProcessor.getFont(PdfCanvasProcessor.java:490)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.canvas.parser.PdfCanvasProcessor$SetTextFontOperator.invoke(PdfCanvasProcessor.java:811)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.canvas.parser.PdfCanvasProcessor.invokeOperator(PdfCanvasProcessor.java:454)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.canvas.parser.PdfCanvasProcessor.processContent(PdfCanvasProcessor.java:282)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.canvas.parser.PdfCanvasProcessor.processPageContent(PdfCanvasProcessor.java:303)
    at com.example.pdf.util.Test.test(Test.java:138)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you add content to a `PdfDocument` like you do here

```java
Document document = new Document(pdfDoc);

Paragraph title = new Paragraph(new Text("index"))
    .setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
document.add(title);
```

you have to be aware that this content is not already stored in its final form; for example fonts used are not yet properly subset'ed. The final form is generated when you're closing the document.

Text extraction on the other hand *requires* the content to extract to be in its final form.

Thus, you should not apply text extraction to a document you're working on. In particular, don't apply text extraction to a page you've changed the content of.

If you need to extract text from the documents you create yourself, close your document first, open a new document from the output, and extract from that new document.